# Index page not opening when run as a project through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am very much a beginner on Java & Eclipse but I hope someone can help

I have created a dynamic web project called Evo16Test, within this from the project I have MyServlet.java and then from WebContent I have index.jsp

When i run the project http://localhost:8080/Evo16Test/

I get HTTP Status 404 error 
The requested resource is not available

If i change the address bar manually to

http://localhost:8080/Evo16Test/Index.jsp

everything works correctly

I thought this could be an error with web.xml but that looks correct shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Evo16Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.srk.pkg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am running Tomcat V7

Thanks for your help

Comment: If it's not a typo your page's real name is `Index.jsp` (capital I as first character) but you specified a non-existing page `index.jsp` in you web.xml

Comment: That has solved it thank you for your help. So easy but I must have spent 2 hours looking for this, including deleting everything and re-installing.

Comment: @AdrewThompson: You're welcome. By the way don't think those efforts worth nothing. If you try to solve your problems by yourself, you will never forget the solutions.